# How to access "Advanced" settings tab on your motherboard's BIOS setup utility, if it's hidden by default on your Laptop/Notebook?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios

Main screen of my motherboard bios setup utility:

[image]]

Is it because, it's a consumer notebook, that I'll never be able to change advanced settings of my BIOS?

I simply want to change VRAM of my laptop/notebook.

How can I change advanced VRAM settings of my BIOS?

Comment: Modded (unlocked BIOS) usually solves this but it's kinda risky to flash BIOS'es

Answer (score 3):

For some laptop models this works :

1. Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to enter BIOS during boot (or whatever is the right key)
2. Press immediately the <kbd>A</kbd> key (for "Advanced")

For some other models, this works :

1. Boot into BIOS
2. Press 3 times <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Reboot into BIOS

There are modded versions of your BIOS that unlock immediately this option,
but the risk to your computer makes it irresponsible for me to recommend them.